# ZFS one HDD vdev hard drive lifetime issue

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, nas, zfs, freenas

I have a travel NAS made of small itx computer with large capacity HDD. Because I was concerned about data rotting issue, I installed NAS4Free, cut the HDD into 10 partitions and made a ZFS RaidZ1 vdev. The drive was Seagate Archive 8Tb and it died just after about 4 month. For some reason, the system was writing something on the hard drive continuously, without any stops. It had Owncloud installed, with all it's files (system and data) stored on ZFS dataset.

Now I am replacing the hard drive with WD, so my question is: how much does such a setup affect the HDD lifetime? I am sure the mechanics should wear out faster, but not sure how bad it is exactly.

Comment: "cut the HDD into 10 partitions and made a ZFS" - this is your issue. The whole point of ZFS is to keep data on different PHYSICAL devices. If you keeping all of your money with you in different pockets, it will not protect you assets if some hooligan rob you, you will loose everything, but if you keep some money in a bank and some of it at home, well you get the point, the same with ZFS. You put heads of HDD in situation where it should constantly moving between partitions and all of it is useless since if hdd fail - you will loose everything regardless redundancy you set

Comment: By creating a RAIDZ1 (RAID 5) on a single disk, you made it experience three times the seek load. That’s not what the Archive HDD is made for and probably what effectively killed it. If you want single-disk redundancy, use the `copies` option. 50% storage efficiency is still plenty if you’re concerned about safety.

Comment: @DanielB would something like WD Purple be a better choice for such setup? They position it as a drive for continuous read-writes, like in video surveillance systems.

Answer (score 2):

Putting more than one leg of a RAID set (no matter which level) on the same disk is a bad idea:

- the only errors it might catch are abd sectors
- this is by far outweighted by the immense head positioning load

With 10 partitions you will see an over 10fold increase in positioning load, when raid scrubbing jumps in you will see persistant drive activity over days, months or years.

If you care about bitrot: ZFS will detect that even with a single leg due to checksumming.
The chance of it being able to correct it with a single leg is zero, but the important part is, that this chance doesn't increase dramatically with another leg on the same disk: The probability of the disk failing prematurely due to the increased stress by far overweighs the chance of a correctable error due to localized sector falure.

Comment: How can ZFS take care of that with a single leg with no redundancy?
I only know of the "copies" option, but that is essentially mirroring and reducing the storage at least 2 times

Comment: ZFS employs 256 bit checksums end-to-end to validate data stored under its protection. But using ZFS on a single drive as was said by CTO of iXsystems - something like "single disk ZFS is so pointless it's actually worse than not using ZFS"

Comment: @Alex: The purpose of StackExchange community is to provide qualified answers (in polite form) to the questions. Not the quotes from WTFIS that you don't even seem to understand.
"It is pointless" exactly because checksums provide no way to restore your data, so using ZFS with vdev, consisting of 1 hdd, provide no redundancy. Now, no matter who said what, there are good reasons to use ZFS even in such setup.

Comment: I used the setup I described above exactly for the reason that Seagate drives failed me in the past. And it worked perfectly this time: once I got first error messages - I simply copied all data to another drive, with no data loss (thank to ZFS partition-made-vdev's redundancy).
The question is how much such setup reduces the drives life-time. Linear reduction does not seem to be high price for reliability, but I prefer to make it certain, preferably with expert answers.

Comment: @AntonLyubinin :-/ I cant see where I provided information for you in non "polite form", but I see how you judging me telling - "don't even seem to understand" even you haven't clue how many ZFS based servers I managing. I already told you that setting ZFS on a single device is useless and stressful for hdd when you splitting hdd to many partitions. If opinion of Mike Lauth is WTFIS for you then I have nothing to say you something else

Comment: @Alex Assuming another person don't have a clue about what he does (this is what your comments, basically, are saying) and writing comments with zero useful information and quotes out of context, praising "authorities" - that's what I would expect from a 15-year-old, definitely what I am not after here. Though thank you for your time.

Comment: @Alex I don't know the exact quote you've related to, but the statement you made is debatable: even a single basic vdev detects bit rot and partial hard drive failure like Unrecoverable read errors (URE). It cannot correct them without a second disk, but detection helps you to know what is up with your data (so you can make separate backups etc).

Comment: @user121391 There no needs to run RAIDZ1 on the same disk to detect disk errors since ZFS  use 256 bit checksums end-to-end to validate data and regular scrubbing will spot such issues. OP split disks to multiple partitions and used them as vdev's array. Such setup will require ZFS access multiple partitions which requiring hdd's R/W heads continuously moving between partitions that create huge overload to mechanical parts of hdd and slowdown disks access since seeking between hdd tracks - it is hdd's bottleneck.

Comment: @user121391 If u repaired HDD then you probably saw failing patterns. It rare if HDD get damaged sectors just in some particular spot that took some small group of continued sectors. Usually failing pattern repeated over some gap between tracks that touch huge area of HDD plates. In OP's setup, if 2 out of 10 partitions will be damaged then the whole RAIDZ1 array will be broken. If there is a case of important data on a single hdd it better to use `par2` utility on regular basis that will help to recover damaged data in cases if small group of hdd's sectors got broken.

Comment: @Alex Sorry, my comment was unclear. I was only focusing on your last sentence (which I also edited), the rest I agree with.

Comment: @user121391 Note that in ZFS critical metadata is stored in `copies`+1 copies, plus any applicable vdev redundancy. Thus, with `copies=1`, you get two copies of critical metadata, plus whatever redundancy level you otherwise choose (jbod, n-way mirror, raidz2, ...). The überblocks are always stored in four copies per device (not vdev); that can be verified using `zdb` if you are so inclined. So if you are lucky, and the corruption happens to hit *just* the right spot, data errors on a JBOD pool are recoverable; also as Eugen said, unless you turn off checksumming, errors are always detectable.